# Python3 importing files in different directories

Tags: python-3.x, import

```
application
 ├── app
 │   └── folder
 │       └── file_1.py
 │       └── file_2.py
 └── app2
     └── folder2
         └── file_3.py
```

I created a file_3 and trying to use classes defined in file_1.

I tried to import using the following method but had an issue because file_1 is importing file_2 which then was raising an error.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/.../application/app/folder')
import file_1
```

How can I import file_1 to file_3 and all the files file_1 is depending on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to folder2 and do this

```
from app.folder.file_1 import classeName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is explained in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path). If I further understand you correctly, `file_1`is using classes from `file_2`? So my guess would be, that you also have to `import file_2` aswell because the current working directory does not contain a file named  `file_2`.